# GreenFunction Computation for perturbed Laplacian

Tags: differential-equations

I am happy computing the Green function for the Laplacian

```
Gsol := GreenFunction[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]}, 
  u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ FullRegion[2], {m, n}]
```

it gives an analytical solution - which is great.

However,  if I slightly perturb my operator

```
Gsol := GreenFunction[{D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + 2 D[u[x, y], {y, 2}]}, 
  u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ FullRegion[2], {m, n}]
```

where I have simply put a 2 infront of the second derivative.

Mathematica is no longer able to provide an analytical or even a numerical approximation to the Green function for this operator. If `GreenFunction` is not able to handle such an operator, is there another method I can use to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: related [using-greenfunction-in-2d-free-space-for-laplacian](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209662/using-greenfunction-in-2d-free-space-for-laplacian)

Comment: Hi Ulrich, Beyond the fact that we both mentioned `GreenFunction` method, can you tell me how that post has a similar problem to me?

Comment: Hi, it's the same problem , and another view, not more. If you could provide some boundary conditions it might be possible to get numerical approximation.

Comment: Ah, I see! How would a numerical approximation would work if I took `{x, y} \[Element] Disk[]` with `DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]` ? `GreenFunction` doesn't seem to like that either

Answer (score 3):

Here my idea (see comments) to get a  numerical approximation for Green's function:

First one needs an approximation of `DiracDelta`, for example

```
eps = .001; (*sufficient small*)
dirac = Function[x, Exp[-(x^2/(2 eps))]/Sqrt[2 Pi eps]]
```

`GreenFunction` is the solution of `D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + 2 D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] ==  dirac[x - \[Xi]] dirac[y - \[Eta]]`

```
 green = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + 2 D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == dirac[x - \[Xi]] dirac[y - \[Eta]], 
 DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]},u , {x, y} \[Element] Disk[] , {\[Xi], \[Eta]}]
```

green's function `g[\[Xi], \[Eta]][x,y]`

```
Plot3D[g[0.1, 0.3][x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], PlotRange -> All ]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, zero Dirichlet b.c. isn't that suitable actually. Just consider the `GreenFunction[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}]}, u[x, y], {x, y} ∈ FullRegion[2], {m, n}]` case, the Green's function isn't tending to zero at infinity.

Comment: @xzcd Thanks, I realize that these finite b.c. doesn't approximate the infinite case, I only tried to show the principle way to get a numerical approximation.

Answer (score 1):

As a new introduced function, `GreenFunction` is still fragile in my view. (The post linked by Ulrich in the comment is another example. ) As to your specific problem, the only work-around I can think out at the moment is to directly solve the PDE with Fourier transform, I'll use [`ft`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71393/1871) to facilitate coding:

```
(* Definition of ft isn't included in this post, 
   please find it in the link above. *)

eq = D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + 2 D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == - DiracDelta[x - m] DiracDelta[y - n];

rule = HoldPattern@FourierTransform[a_, __] :> a;

teq = ft[eq, x, w1] /. rule /. u -> (U@#2 &)

tteq = ft[teq, y, w2] /. rule /. U[y] -> υ

ttsol = Solve[tteq, υ] // Values // Flatten // First

sol = InverseFourierTransform[ttsol, {w2, w1}, {y, x}]
```

Notice `u -> (U@#2 &)` and `U[y] -> υ` aren't actually necessary, they're just
to make the code more readable.

The `sol` is a bit lengthy and not that easy to simplify, so I'd like to show another way to calculate the inverse Fourier transform that produces a simpler result. We know inverse Fourier transform is essentially an integral, but in this case the generic function has involved in so we can't use `Integrate` to calculate the inverse transform directly, nevertheless, utilizing the differentiation property of Fourier transform:

```
FourierTransform[f'[t], t, ω]
(* -I ω FourierTransform[f[t], t, ω] *)
```

we can calculate derivative of the fundamental solution:

```
dsol = -(1/Sqrt[2 Pi])^2 Integrate[
   Exp[-I ( w1 x + w2 y)] ttsol w1 w2, {w1, -Infinity, Infinity}, {w2, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}, Assumptions -> (x | y | m | n) ∈ Reals]

(* ConditionalExpression[(
 Sqrt[2] (m - x) Abs[n - y] Sign[n - y])/(π (2 (m - x)^2 + (n - y)^2)^2), n != y] *)
```

Finally integrate with respect to $x$ annd $y$:

```
solalter = 
 Integrate[dsol, x, y, Assumptions -> (x | y | m | n) ∈ Reals && n != y] // 
  FullSimplify
(* -(Log[2 (m - x)^2 + (n - y)^2]/(4 Sqrt[2] π)) *)
```

"Wait, haven't you ignored the constant? " Indeed, but it doesn't hurt because fundamental solution is not unique. Actually it's not hard to show by numeric tests that:

```
sol - solalter == (-2 EulerGamma + Log[2])/(4 Sqrt[2] π)
```

Sadly, this method doesn't seem to be easy to generalize to cases like `D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + x^2 D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == - DiracDelta[x - m] DiracDelta[y - n]` as asked in comment.

Comment: This approach looks very promising, Thanks! It works perfectly for constant coefficients. For my use case I need it to work for non-constant coefficients. For instance, a(x,y) = x^2 instead of simply a constant 2. Looks like DChange has trouble with this, as I am getting an 'iteration limit exceeded' . Do you have much experience with that sort of error?

Comment: @jcm After a second thought I notice the `DChange`-based solution is wrong. (I forgot the RHS of the equation. ) Answer rewritten, now it should be correct. Sadly I can't think out a way to generalize this method to handle the new example you mentioned.